# CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_AFFINITY_DOMAIN not supported in the Intel/AMD OpenCL CPU runtime

Tags: multithreading, opencl, intel, amd-processor, numa

**Conditions:**

I installed AMD OpenCL version *AMD-APP-SDK-v2.8-lnx64* and Intel OpenCL version  *intel_sdk_for_ocl_applications_xe_2013_r2_sdk_3.1.1.11385_x64* (version identification couldn't be more complex) according to the description on an HPC server with a dual socket **Xeon** E5-2650, Xeon Phi coprocessor, 64GB host memory and Red Hat Enterprise Server 6.4.

**Problem description:**

I would like to do **device fission** with **OpenCL** to get around the **NUMA** issue. Unfortunately the device (Intel CPU) or maybe the Linux kernel doesn't seem to support **CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_AFFINITY_DOMAIN**. I tried both Intel OpenCL and AMD OpenCL. Although AMD OpenCL device query says that it supports the affinity domain option, actually it doesn't: when I try to run a code with CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_BY_AFFINITY_DOMAIN the clCreateSubDevices() function returns with -30 error code. I guess this is a bug in the current Intel OpenCL driver, according to a [forum post](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/377784).

**Potential solution:**

I thought that if I could select the first 16 parallel compute cores (8 cores + 8 hyper threads) (out of the total 32 parallel compute cores) those would map to the first socket. Unfortunately Intel OpenCL randomly distributes the 16 parallel compute cores across the 32 cores. AMD OpenCL on the other hand select the first 16 parallel compute cores, but the OpenCL compiler does a poor job on the kernel I'm running. So the no free lunch theorem applies here as well.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to specify which parallel compute cores the OpenCL should use for the computations?
2. Is there any way to overcome this NUMA issue with OpenCL?

Any comments regarding experiences with NUMA affinity are welcome.

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

*A partial workaround, only applicable to single-socket testing:*

(In Linux) Disable all cores from a NUMA node, so OpenCL ICD can only choose from hardware threads of the other NUMA node. Eg. on a 2 socket 32 HTT system:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu31/online"
....
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/online"
```

I'm not sure if this hacking has no side effect, but so far it seems to work (for testing at least).

Comment: You can first divide to 32 pieces then join 16 of them  by picking through user interface that asks "is any of the first 16 cores %100 active?" then adds to list.

Comment: Wait, are you using OpenCL only for 16 work-items??? It is obvious that the performance will be poor, but not because the NUMA problem.

Comment: huseyin: yes, all the 16 CPU cores are running on 100%. Unfortunately I don't see any way of picking cores through UI - I don't think it's possible.

DarkZeros: Does are 16 CPU cores (with OpenCL terms: parallel compute cores/units). I'm definitely worried about the NUMA issue. I modified the post to be more precise.

Comment: Okay, if you know physical addresses of each numa node, then prepare some arrays in each of them, then use those datas for computing. Do a benchmark for each core/thread separately. Then join similar-point-awarded cores in single fission and other part as another fission. Example: half of the threads will have 1200 points and other half will have 70 points so you can group them.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik AFAIK there is no way of indexing cores in OpenCL. All you can do is tell: "I want 16 cores" and you can also specify how to select them: "select does that are on a common L3 cache or NUMA socket etc."